# How can a delete vote be deleted?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

Today I stumbled upon a [NAA, downvoted and voted to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17543824/203657). Now the vote shows up in my votes list as being deleted (and the NAA is living on happily):

[image]

The earlier (from 24.6) is one of my own answers which I deleted/undeleted, so it looks like the delete in the upper somehow means my vote got reverted - by whom and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post in question was deleted, then undeleted by the OP. See the [post revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17543824/revisions).

When the post was deleted, your deletion vote was cleared too.

I've flagged it as NAA, and cast a deletion vote. Others did so too, and the post has now been 'properly' deleted.

Comment: And... now it's gone.

Comment: ahh ... good to know, thanks

Comment: I think it can still be undeleted by the answer author, we better keep an eye over this.

Comment: I don't think you can undelete when deleted by the community. It'll require a mod or undelete votes from others.

Comment: My bad, the case I had in mind was the ability to clear close votes by self deleting and undeleting. Still worth testing though... will use my sock if time allows it. :-)